# Ubuntu Unity's dodge does not work after the update (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, unity, updates, minimize

Ubuntu Unity's dodge does not work after today's update  in Ubuntu 12.04.

These commands do not help:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ikarosdev/unity-revamped
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:garhuy/unity
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of those PPA have not been updated. Hence, the Unity version in those PPAs [are](https://launchpad.net/~ikarosdev/+archive/unity-revamped) [older](https://launchpad.net/~garhuy/+archive/unity) than the ones in the official repositories. Consequently, your system updated Unity using the packages provided in the official repositories.

You could either wait for the one of the PPAs to be updated (and your system will automatically use it) or you can use Synaptics to force your system to use one of the PPAs. The latter method is not recommended, as it could break something and you would also loose [these](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/unity/5.20.0-0ubuntu2) bug fixes from your system.

If you absolutely want to downgrade the packages, open Synaptics, select the `unity-2d` package. Then, select "force version" from the Package menu or hit Ctrl+E and follow the instructions on the screen. You may need to repeat these steps for the `unity` package or any other `unity-2d` package.